# What does "as to" mean?

Tags: word-usage

What does "as to" mean in this sentence "My English teacher's humor was such as to make every student burst into laughter."?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually you can find your answer in the dictionary easily

Comment: You're misparsing the interrelationships between individual words. There the collocation ***such as*** (meaning *of a type that/which*) and the infinitive verb form ***to make***. Those two elements could both be replaced by alternative forms - *"His humour was **of a type that made** everyone laugh"*.

Answer (score 2):

*As to* here is a piece of the construction *BE such as to VERB*.

In this construction, *such* represents, approximately, *of such a quality or character*, and the entire construction may be paraphrased as *HAVE a quality which VERB*.

> My English teacher's humor had a quality which made every student burst into laughter.

In this particular instance, however, the semantics are a little more complicated. What you are talking about **is** a 'quality', humor, ascribed to the English teacher. Consequently, you may understand the collocation of *humor* and *such* as *so humorous*, and paraphrase this whole as

> My English teacher was so humorous that he made every student burst into laughter.

The construction *such as to* is old-fashioned and rather pompous now ; I advise you to  avoid it in your own writing and aim instead at more direct expressions, like my second paraphrase.

Comment: Definitely the right kind of answer for ELL. First, tell 'em what some construction *means*, and how the syntax hangs together (unless it's just some irregular idiomatic usage). Then offer pragmatic advice on whether it's worth the average learner aspiring to actually incorporate the form into their own utterances. For an awful lot of things learners find "strange", the best advice is *not* to incorporate them into one's own speech/writing, even if they are "valid".